# is using "this" a form of polymorphism?

Tags: android

i have a class called LauncherActivity that extends FragmentActivity as shown:

```
  public class LauncherActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  public Context mContext;
  private Common mApp;
  public Activity mActivity;
    mContext = this;
    mActivity = this;
    mApp = (Common) mContext.getApplicationContext();
```

i have read about polymorphism and gotten to know the main use is to use parent references to access child objects.Since LaucherActivity is the child class and FragmentActivity is the parent class,and FragmentActivity is a child class of the Context class in reference to the android documentation, using this as shown below is allowed ? is it a form of polymorphism?:

```
    mContext = this;
    mActivity = this;
```

am presume this refers to the current object which is LauncherActivity ?

Comment: Activity extends Context. Therefore mContext = this is valid, like it is for mActivity = this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually , `this` keyword is uses to say that , refers to the context of the current activity.

Comment: And what is the benefit of doing this ? Why not just do this like in the documentation   mContext= getApplicationContext ?

Comment: In here,this keyword can be used to return the current class instance.

Comment: By saying that it reffers to the context of the current activity what do you mean ?Am having a hard time time understanding the meaning of context even in the documentation.If so what about the other part  mActivity = this ?

Comment: do you want to know about, what is a context?

Comment: Yeah , i have tried reading on it but if you have a simpler explanation that would be very helpful

Comment: Context objects are so common, and get passed around so frequently, it can be easy to create a situation you didn’t intend.  Loading resources, launching a new Activity, obtaining a system service, getting internal file paths, and creating views all require a Context  Not all Context instances are created equal.  Depending on the Android application component, the Context you have access to varies slightly:

Comment: Okay i think that will help let me dig into it

Comment: so if you got something for question vote :) and if you want more help let me know